# Sticky navbar not fixed after scrolling

Tags: html, css

I followed a tutorial about sticky navbar with pure css without javascript. The problem is that the sticky navigation bar is not fixed at the top of the page when i scroll down. Under this sticky navbar I have 3 other sections. Every time I scroll down the page that the navbar goes under sections and does not work anymore. In the header I have a full-width image and I have some text and a button on it.

Here is my code of navbar in HTML:

```css
header {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(black, transparent, black), url(images/architecture2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 100px;
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.intro .inner {
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
}

.content h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.content p {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.btnD1 {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 16.5px 50px;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#despre">Despre Noi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#calatorii">Calatorii</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SignIn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="content">
            <h1>C&#259l&#259tore&#351te cu noi &#238n jurul lumii</h1>
            <p>Destina&#355ia visat&#259 este la un click distan&#355&#259!</p>
            <a class="btnD1" href="#">Rezerv&#259 acum</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks!

Comment: The sticky element works relative to it's direct parent, if you set the `nav` to sticky but the `header` goes out the screen then the `nav` will go out the screen too with it. Make the `header` sticky instead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it behave is the use of `z-index` in the `.intro .inner` class. You will need to set the `z-index: 11;` on the `.nav` class for it to appear on top of everything.

```css
header {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(black, transparent, black), url(images/architecture2.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: table;
  top: 0;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 100px;
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.intro .inner {
  margin-top: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 10;
  color: #fff;
}

.content h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
}

.content p {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -35px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.btnD1 {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 16.5px 50px;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#despre">Despre Noi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#calatorii">Calatorii</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SignIn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
          <div class="content">
            <h1>C&#259l&#259tore&#351te cu noi &#238n jurul lumii</h1>
            <p>Destina&#355ia visat&#259 este la un click distan&#355&#259!</p>
            <a class="btnD1" href="#">Rezerv&#259 acum</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> If you're not sure what other `z-index` values you gonna use. Most people set it to `999` for things that supposed to appear on top of everything at all times.

Comment: It doesn't work. It stops at the end of the first section

Comment: When you say **first section**; are you referring to the `div.intro` or the `header` section?

Answer (score 0):

The `nav` is sticky, but only within it's parent (which is the `.header`). To fix this, simply make the `.header` sticky - this way it will be sticky as long as it's parent (which is `.wrapper`) is being scrolled.

And also give it a higher z-index than it's siblings (`.intro inner` has `z-index: 10`), or it will come underneath the `intro inner` when scrolled pass it :

```
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

Comment: It won't work as you think since the `div.intro` is also within the same block. So you would still end up having the `nav` goes below the content as it does now

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that sticky propriety. i removed that from the nav and i added a transition and z-index as well.

```
nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    top: 0;
    z-index:999;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

nav ul{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 100px;
    float:right;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 90px;
}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Make your wrapper's Height auto. this will fix your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).